# PHP mutiple queries no result in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an android app that requires connection to a database. I have the android part working but I'm having trouble with my php script.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(/This info is correct/) or die ("Unable to connect");

$gebruikersnaamOntvanger = $_POST["gebruikersnaamOntvanger"];
$idBetaler = $_POST["idBetaler"];
$bedrag = $_POST["bedrag"];
$saldoBetaler = $_POST["saldo"];
$response = array();
$response["success"] = "false";

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT idGebruiker, Saldo FROM Gebruikers WHERE Gebruikersnaam = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $gebruikersnaamOntvanger);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $idGebruiker, $Saldo);

while($row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $idOntvanger = $idGebruiker;  
    $saldoOntvanger = $Saldo;
}

$saldoOntvanger += $bedrag;
$saldoBetaler -= $bedrag;


try {

    $statement2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Transacties (idBetaler, idOntvanger, Bedrag, Datum, Uitgevoerd) VALUES(?, ?, ?, now(), 1)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement2, "iid", $idBetaler, $idOntvanger, $bedrag);  
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement2);

    $response["success"] = "success";

} catch(Exception $e) {
    $response["success"] = $e->gettext;
}


echo json_encode($response);
 ?>
```

So the android part work and returns the JSON object correctly but nothing changes in the database. I have tried adding a try catch so I get what's the error but the try catch never works. The script alwayws returns success even if it didn't work. Please be aware I'm new to PHP and I have double checked the SQL queries and they should be correct. If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_* function dosn't throws exceptions. So your catch is never executed even on error. Change your code like this :

```
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($statement2))
         throw new Exception(mysqli_stmt_error($statement2));
```

When you'll see the error you can fix your code. May be add same error handling to mysqli_prepare and others

Comment: I was able to figure out where my error was by using your code. Thank you for informing me how to use try catch properly in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was the use of `iid` in the binding for the insert query. It should either be `iis` or `iii` presumably. You tried using `try/catch` blocks but to my mind did not make full use of them - the creation of a `prepared statement` should be tested to see if it succeeds or fails ~ the outcome of which can be used in the `try/catch` logic to indicate faults. Excuse the mix of `procedural` and `OOP` style code

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST["gebruikersnaamOntvanger"], $_POST["idBetaler"], $_POST["bedrag"], $_POST["saldo"] ) ){

        try{

            $con = mysqli_connect(/This info is correct/) or die ("Unable to connect");

            $gebruikersnaamOntvanger = $_POST["gebruikersnaamOntvanger"];
            $idBetaler = $_POST["idBetaler"];
            $bedrag = $_POST["bedrag"];
            $saldoBetaler = $_POST["saldo"];

            $response = array('success'=>false);

            $stmt=$conn->prepare( 'select `idgebruiker`, `saldo` from `gebruikers` where `gebruikersnaam` = ?' );
            if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception('unable to prepare select query');
            else {

                $stmt->bind_param( 's', $gebruikersnaamOntvanger );
                $result=$stmt->execute();
                if( !$result )throw new Exception('No results from select query');
                else {

                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result( $idGebruiker, $Saldo );

                    while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                        $idOntvanger = $idGebruiker;  
                        $saldoOntvanger = $Saldo;                       
                    }

                    $saldoOntvanger += $bedrag;
                    $saldoBetaler -= $bedrag;                   


                    $stmt=$con->prepare('insert into `transacties` ( `idbetaler`, `idontvanger`, `bedrag`, `datum`, `uitgevoerd` ) values(?, ?, ?, now(), 1)');
                    if( !$stmt )throw new Exception('Unable to prepare insert query');
                    else {

                        /* What is the value of $bedrag? integer, string?? */
                        /*
                            The binding iid was incorrect - perhaps iis or iii
                        */
                        $stmt->bind_param('iis', $idBetaler, $idOntvanger, $bedrag );
                        $result = $stmt->execute();
                        $response['success']=$result;

                    }
                }
            }

            echo json_encode( $response );

        }catch( Exception $e ){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: One of the variables is a double, in the database it is a decimal. So I can't use i.

Comment: ok - I would test then that the value of `$bedrag` is indeed a float - ie: `is_float( $bedrag )`